# Change ui-state in meteor-angular application after creating any entry

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm new to METEOR. I created an application using meteor and angular. But I'm struggling with the redirection stuff. I want to redirect to list page after creating an entry .

find below code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

class ProsperFilterAdd {
    constructor($stateParams, $scope, $reactive, $location) {
      'ngInject';
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    }

    save(){
      this.call('filters.insert', this.formData);
      // TODO: NEED TO REDIRECT AT LIST PAGE OF FILTERS
    }
}

export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor,
    uiRouter
]).component(name, {
    templateUrl: `imports/ui/components/${name}/${name}.html`,
    controllerAs: name,
    controller: ProsperFilterAdd
   })
   .config(config);

   function config($stateProvider) {
       'ngInject';
       $stateProvider
         .state('prosper_filter_create', {
         url: '/prosper_filters/create',
         template: '<prosper-filter-add></prosper-filter-add>'
       });
   }
```

Please guide me, where I'm doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go(STATE_NAME)` code. The you controller will look like

```
class ProsperFilterAdd {
    constructor($stateParams, $state, $scope, $reactive, $location) {
      'ngInject';
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    } //removed ); here

    save(){
      this.call('filters.insert', this.formData);
      // TODO: NEED TO REDIRECT AT LIST PAGE OF FILTERS
      $state.go('prosper_filter_create');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you inject the $state into the controller ? check -  constructor($stateParams, $state, $scope, $reactive, $location) line

Comment: Yes, I injected. constructor($stateParams, $state, $scope, $reactive, $location)

Comment: you have to figure out why **Error: $state is not defined** happens, $state.go is a regular way of switching states in angular-ui-router (http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/routing-and-multiple-views)

Comment: Correct, I did this change also. But nothing works. Same Error: **$state is not defined**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110996/discussion-between-user1787700-and-shershen).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right way to do it.

```
class ProsperFilterAdd {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $state) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$state = $state;

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    }
    save(){
        this.$state.go('prosper_filter_create');
    }
}
```